# Dojo GridX align column header vertically

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojo.gridx

Is it possible to align column header vertically in dojo gridX ?

I want the gridX structure like this:

`|------------------------------------------|
 |  Column 1   | value 1     | value 2      |
 |------------ |-------------|--------------|
 |  Column 2   | value 1     | value 2      |
 |-------------|-------------|--------------|
 |  Column 3   | value 1     | value 2      |
 |-------------|-------------|--------------|
 |  Column 4   | value 1     | value 2      |
 |------------------------------------------|`